# Strange StringBuilder

Tags: powershell, stringbuilder

I have StringBuilder object inside function. There are **string-type** before return and some **System.Object** after.

```
function test
{
    $strArr = @("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
    $stringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
    foreach ($item in $strArr)
    {
        $stringBuilder.AppendLine($item)            
    }
    $out = $stringBuilder.ToString()
    write-host "FIRST OUT: ", $out, "OUTTYPE:", $out.GetType()
    return $out
}

$out2 = test
Write-Host "-------------------"
write-host "SECOND OUT2: ", $out2, "OUT2TYPE:", $out2.GetType()
```

Output:

```
FIRST OUT:  aaa
bbb
ccc
 OUTTYPE: System.String -> THAT'S OK
-------------------
SECOND OUT2 (ALL ARE four times - WHY???):  aaa
bbb
ccc
 aaa
bbb
ccc
 aaa
bbb
ccc 
 aaa
bbb
ccc
 OUT2TYPE: System.Object[] -> Object?????
```

Why are all four times? Why object not string?

Answer (score 5):

Just try this :

```
function test

    {
    $strArr = @("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
    $stringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
    foreach ($item in $strArr)
    {
        $stringBuilder.AppendLine($item) | Out-Null           
    }
    $out = $stringBuilder.ToString()
    write-host "FIRST OUT: ", $out, "OUTTYPE:", $out.GetType()
    return $out
}

$out2 = test
Write-Host "-------------------"
write-host "SECOND OUT2: ", $out2, "OUT2TYPE:", $out2.GetType()
```

Explanation is that `$stringBuilder.AppendLine()` output something, and it's added to the output of the function.

---

Edited :
Everything that a function output is considered as the return of the function. In other words, in PowerShell, the return value of a function is not only the value after the `return` keywork ($out) but all the data outputed inside the function (in an array form). Looking at [about_Return](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx) we see that

> In Windows PowerShell, the results of each statement are returned as 
>       output, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword.

Comment: That's working, thank you. But i cant' understand: $out - is a new string object...

Comment: @AndrewSemenov The `AppendLine()` function returns a reference to the StringBuilder itself, if you inspect `$out2[0].GetType()` you will see that it's of type `StringBuilder`

Comment: I edit man answer to explain tha the return value is not only $out but all the data outputed inside the function.

Comment: The primary purpose of the Return keyword is to force an immediate exit from the function. Whatever value is specified along with it is optional, and incidental.

Comment: This is subject to discussion. The most common deviation from structured programming is early exit from a function or loop. Even if PowerShell can consider evey output as a returned value, I prefer return a single object at the end, it's more readable, more suitable for maintenance